# Why is my regex is not working in my input field?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following array of props for the different input fields:

```
const inputs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Name',
      required: true,
      pattern: '/^[a-zA-Z]$/',
      errorMessage: 'Only letters are allowed in this field'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'lastname',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name',
      required: true,
      pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]$',
      errorMessage: 'Only letters are allowed in this field'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Email',
      required: true,
      errorMessage: 'Invalid email'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'confirmEmail',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Confirm Email',
      required: true,
      pattern: values.email,
      errorMessage: 'Emails don´t match'

    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'message',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Message',
      required: true,
      errorMessage: 'This field cannot be empty'
    }
  ]
```

This array contain props such as patterns and error messages to validate my fields. The issue that i have is that my emails fields and message fields work perfect their validation pattern and the error message dissapears when the value passed the validation.
Now in the case of my fields name and lastname, the pattern for accepting only letters is not working. I enter only letters in those fields and the error message is still showing and im not able to submit the form.

```
return (
    <form className='contactForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {inputs.map((input) => (
        <FormInput 
        key={input.id} 
        {...input} 
        value={values[input.name]} 
        onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
      <SubmitBtn/>
      
      
    </form>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

FormInput.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './FormInput.css';
import { Input } from '../atoms/Input';
import ErrorSpan from '../atoms/ErrorSpan';

const FormInput = (props) => {

  const { id, onChange, errorMessage, ...inputProps } = props;

  return (
    <div className='formInput'>
        {/* <label htmlFor="">Username</label> */}
         <Input {...inputProps} onChange={onChange} /> 
        <ErrorSpan errorMessage={props.errorMessage}/>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

ErrorSpan.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './ErrorSpan.css'

const ErrorSpan = (props) => {

    const {errorMessage} = props;

  return (
    <span>{errorMessage}</span>
  )
}

export default ErrorSpan
```

Input.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './Input.css'

export const Input = (props) => {

    const { id, onChange, ...inputProps } = props;
    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false)

    const handleFocused = (e) =>{
        setFocused(true)
      }

  return (
    <input {...inputProps} onChange={onChange} onBlur={handleFocused} focused={focused.toString()}/>
  )
}
```

Is the following the correct validation pattern for just letters?

```
pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]$'
```

Comment: You don't show what a `FormInput` is

Comment: You don't show us what an `Input` is. How are we supposed to know what your own code does with the `pattern` prop? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question with more debugging details.

Comment: Done, pasted `FormInput.js`,  `Input` component it is just a input field, and `ErrorSpan` its just a span. 
@AndyRay

Comment: Check the documentation, this isn't related to react. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern Don't use wrapping `/` slashes and `^[a-zA-Z]$` is the start of a string, exactly one character, then the end of string. You want `^[a-zA-Z]+$`